# Input focused but not typable

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have an `<input readonly="true">` element. I have it set to do remove the readonly attribute and focus the element when it's double-clicked. I can see the readonly attribute is removed, and the cursor blinks in the text field. However, when I type, nothing happens. If I double click again (single clicking doesn't do anything), I can type. Why is this?

https://jsfiddle.net/kkj1wtef/

I'm experiencing this in Chrome. Weirdly, in Firefox the readonly attribute doesn't seem to work at all.

Comment: your fiddle works for me in chrome.

Comment: does https://jsfiddle.net/opndewy5/ work any better for you? i've had the same issue with "dblclick decay" in chrome before.

Comment: @JanR It works in my browser, either.

Comment: @dandavis unfortunately same issue

Comment: @JanR are you sure you're only double clicking once? I've verified this behavior on other computers with other users locally.

Comment: can you use jQuery ???

Comment: @NietzscheProgrammer Why would that make a difference?

Comment: try the code I placed in my answer and let me know. I am working in another solution with pure JS

Comment: Definitely only double clicking once..

Comment: @Asherlc I'm also seeing it not work unless I double click twice in chrome

Comment: i can partially reproduce this in chrome by double-clicking while i type, which discards many keystrokes before the letters are added to the input. if your computer is slower, it might be more than a few...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For whatever reason, this seems to solve the issue:

```
input.addEventListener('dblclick', function() {
    input.removeAttribute('readonly');
    input.blur();
    input.focus();
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kkj1wtef/2/

Comment: `For whatever reason` - Any idea at all what that reason might be?!

Comment: Probably a race condition - it gets double clicked, readonly *attribute* is removed, browser gives the input focus and sets the readonly property to false, when the input gets focus it checks the readonly property, for certain machines the readonly property (not attribute) has not been changed yet, so for those machines, it thinks it shouldn't listen for keystrokes.

Comment: @dave Interesting solution! Btw, it works just fine with a single click. What could possibly cause the difference between single vs double click? Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify the javascript code snippet and rename the var to avoid ambiguity:

```
var txtbox = document.querySelector('input');
txtbox.addEventListener('dblclick', function() {
    this.removeAttribute('readonly');
});
```

There is no need to for extra-line setting the focus as the double click will suffice the goal.

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Just tested in every browser you mentioned and it works properly with jQuery

html

```
<input type="text" readonly="true">
```

JS

```
var $input = $('input');

$input.dblclick(function() {
    $input.removeAttr('readonly');
    $input.focus();
});
```

or adding `this` in case the other one doesn't work

```
$input.dblclick(function() {
    $(this).removeAttr('readonly');
    $(this).focus();
});
```

Comment: Neither one works for me. Are you 100% sure you're only doing two mouse clicks?

Comment: @Asherlc yes I am clicking twice. Which Chrome version are you using ?

Comment: Version 49.0.2623.87

Answer (score 0):

In your fiddle in Chrome 48 it always ignores the first character I type, but everything that follows works. I was able to fix it by adding a line after you focus the input.

Set `input.value =  ''`

This fixed the issue for me.

Comment: weird. https://jsfiddle.net/5wdbpa31/ works around the issue too, if there's any value in the input.